# Facebook messenger bot not showing send Location button on ios devices, only in android

Tags: ios, facebook, bots, messenger

I am using the facebook messenger bot api,in android devices it appears to the user the button to send location and continue with the bot flow, but in ios there is not showing the button.

I ve read the messenger documentation, but i didnt see anything relates with this issue.

Ps: I am not trying to use the Location quickReply that is deprecated.

Is there some additional permission that ios requires besides the one that is asked after the first installation of the facebook messenger application?